Raspbian/Debian install Docker - apt https error with Docker repository
Need to install up to date Docker on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+
Can do apt install docker.io but it extremely outdated.
Follow official Docker instruction. After I add repository to Apt sources sudo apt-get update results in error:
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4.

apt version:
apt -v
apt 2.2.4 (armhf)


Deleting /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list restores apt to normal. curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh - result is the same, because script dose same thing.
Wanted to try to install from package, but https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/bullseye/stable/ contains no .deb files.
My OS:
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian

CPU:
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4


The documentation on docker.io is clear, but the structure of the folders a bit misleading.
For example if you need Debian Bullseye for arm64, this link will provide you all the .deb packages :
https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/bullseye/pool/stable/arm64/

In my case it is 32bit, so armhf is proper folder. It worked. Although probably someone will tell how to fix apk, as auto update is preferable.
